# How to clear "Undo" history after closing file in JetBrains WebStorm or PhpStorm or other jetbrains products?

Tags: save, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to clear undo history after file closing? Or in the other words:
How can I disable undo after file closed?

It is a little bit confusing, when you open file, do something and after that you want to rollback, you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and implicitly roll back all changes including previously closed file usage changes.

to reproduce:

1. open file
2. write `A`
3. close file
4. open the same file
5. write `B` after `A`
6. press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

you will see that both changes are gone and this is not a good feature, To me, this risks unintended/accidental changes.

Is there any option to enable/disable this functionality?

Comment: I personally could not find such option. The Undo history is linked to [Local History](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Local+History+in+PhpStorm) .. so instead of doing `Ctrl+Z` few times to rollback to a state at what file was opened ... you may just use Local History to do it in 1 or 2 clicks.

Comment: @LazyOne: Thank you very much for your help and reply, But how can I use `Local History`?

Comment: Well ... I gave you the link to the official How-To article... But just in case here it is again: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Local+History+in+PhpStorm . So the idea is: you right click on a file/editor tab/editor area and choose `Local History | Show History` and there you may rollback to any save point (the most recent is on the top).

Comment: P.S. On actual subject -- the closest ticket that I could find (be it request or bug report etc) is this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108209 -- but it's not clear on what was happening here as there was no response after initial report (over 3 years now). If you wish -- submit specific Feature Request to [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) asking for such dedicated option. But considering how this all Undo/Local History works (you can use Local History to rollback Replace in multiple files in one go) it's rather unlikely to be implemented any time soon.

Comment: It is not a nice feature. Jetbrains should give an option to clear the history easily.